# Stripping effects on Delphi toolbuttons (TToolbutton)

Tags: delphi, colors, toolbar, highlighting

I'm attempting to switch from using Toolbar2000 to the regular toolbar because there doesn't seem to be a Delphi XE2 version and it looks like it uses some Assembly and I just don't really want to deal with it if I don't have to. (and I really like the fade-in effect with the Delphi Toolbar)

But, what I don't like is that the background of the button gets the regular blueish button treatment.  I know how to change the color, but can I just not make the color change and not have a border painted around the button?

I've implemented the 'OnAdvancedCustomDrawButton' but the flags available don't seem to work right and I'm not sure how they interact with the gradient color and the hot track color and I wind up having some weird flashing or weird black backgrounds.

Here's how I'm creating the Toolbar

```
ToolBar1 := TToolBar.Create(Self);
ToolBar1.DoubleBuffered := true;
ToolBar1.OnAdvancedCustomDrawButton := Toolbar1CustomDrawButton;
ToolBar1.Transparent := false;
ToolBar1.Parent := Self;
ToolBar1.GradientEndColor := $7ca0c2; //RGB(194, 160, 124);
ToolBar1.GradientStartColor := $edeeed; //RGB(237, 238, 124);
ToolBar1.Indent := 5;
ToolBar1.Images := Normal;
ToolBar1.DrawingStyle := dsGradient;
ToolBar1.HotImages := Over;
ToolBar1.AutoSize := True;
ToolBar1.Visible := False;
```

and here's how I'm creating the buttons (in a loop):

```
ToolButton := TToolButton.Create(ToolBar1);
ToolButton.Parent := ToolBar1;
ToolButton.ImageIndex := ToolButtonImages[Index].ImageIndex;
ToolButton.OnClick := ToolButtonClick;
```

and here's my AdvancedCustomDrawButton function

```
procedure TMyForm.Toolbar1CustomDrawButton(Sender: TToolBar; Button: TToolButton;
    State: TCustomDrawState; Stage: TCustomDrawStage;
    var Flags: TTBCustomDrawFlags; var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
begin
  Flags := [tbNoEdges, tbNoOffset];
  DefaultDraw := True;
end;
```

Comment: since it's delphi you can Inherit from the parent object and after initialize() you can set the values by overriding it there if you like do you have a code sample of the objects decleration or how you are instantiating the object...?

Comment: OK, I added my code, I don't think it'll help necessarily, but what do you override? I don't think making my own TToolButton will help because the existing paint function isn't even where the stuff I want to get rid of is done.  Maybe I just need to set `defaultdraw := false` and do everything myself.

Comment: where you have this ToolBar1 := TToolBar.Create(Self);  I am thinking you would want change the Instance of that. also I don't see who the owner is I see Parent.. so basically you want to create the object, assign the parent, owner would be the Form or the panel where the control resides, set your properties / creation of that right after the Initialize() you want to have an Inherited line.. I don't have delphi on this laptop it's on my other one..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set drawing style of the toolbar to `dsNormal` and set `Flags` to [tbNoEdges] in custom draw handler.

**update:**

While the above works for 2K and XP, Vista and 7 seem to not to draw the border when button background is not drawn. Unfortunately achieving this with the VCL supplied `TTBCustomDrawFlags` is impossible, so we cannot get rid of the borders in a custom drawing handler.

If the toolbar is on the form itself we can put a handler for `WM_NOTIFY` since notification messages are sent to the parent window:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ..
  private
    procedure WMNotify(var Msg: TWMNotify); message WM_NOTIFY;
    ..
  ..

procedure TForm1.WMNotify(var Msg: TWMNotify);
begin
  inherited;
  if (Msg.NMHdr.code = NM_CUSTOMDRAW) and
      Assigned(Toolbar1) and (Toolbar1.HandleAllocated) and
      (Msg.NMHdr.hwndFrom = ToolBar1.Handle) then

    case PNMTBCustomDraw(Msg.NMHdr).nmcd.dwDrawStage of
      CDDS_PREPAINT: Msg.Result := Msg.Result or CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW;
      CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT: Msg.Result := TBCDRF_NOEDGES or TBCDRF_NOBACKGROUND;
                             // NOEDGES for 2K, XP, // NOBACKGROUND for Vista 7
    end;
end;
```

If the toolbar is parented in another window, like a panel, then we need to subclass the toolbar:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ..
  private
    FSaveToolbarWndProc: TWndMethod;
    procedure ToolbarWndProc(var Msg: TMessage);
    ..
..

uses
  commctrl;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ..
  FSaveToolbarWndProc := ToolBar1.WindowProc;
  ToolBar1.WindowProc := ToolbarWndProc;
end;

procedure TForm1.ToolbarWndProc(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
  FSaveToolbarWndProc(Msg);

  if (Msg.Msg = CN_NOTIFY) and
      (TWMNotify(Msg).NMHdr.hwndFrom = ToolBar1.Handle) and
      (TWMNotify(Msg).NMHdr.code = NM_CUSTOMDRAW) then begin

    case PNMTBCustomDraw(TWmNotify(Msg).NMHdr)^.nmcd.dwDrawStage of
      CDDS_PREPAINT: Msg.Result := CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW;
      CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT: Msg.Result := TBCDRF_NOEDGES or TBCDRF_NOBACKGROUND;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

(Note that drawing style still needs to be `dsNormal`.)

With this solution you don't need to put a handler for custom drawing. But if you need/want to anyway, you might need to 'or' the `Msg.Result` with the one VCL's window procedure returns, i.e the 'case' would look like:

```
  CDDS_PREPAINT: Msg.Result := Msg.Result or CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW;
  CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT: Msg.Result :=
                    Msg.Result or TBCDRF_NOEDGES or TBCDRF_NOBACKGROUND;
```

same goes for when we handle WM_NOTIFY on the form.

There may be other ways to achieve the same, custom drawing is a broad topic. If you want to delve into it, I suggest you to start from the links below for the problem at hand:

[About Custom Draw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff919569%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
[NM_CUSTOMDRAW (toolbar) notification code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760492%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
[NMCUSTOMDRAW structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775483%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
[NMTBCUSTOMDRAW structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760450%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: In particular, I want to disable having the border, IMO using the gradient actually looks better than dsNormal, but this doesn't solve the problem.  What I want to get rid of is the border.

Comment: I tried it and it looked identical.  Maybe that has something to do with buttons with real captions instead of buttons that are just pictures.

Comment: @Peter - Initially I tested on XP and it worked, now checked on Vista and 7 and you're right. AFAICS the VCL returns the proper result for NM_CUSTOMDRAW but these OS seem to ignore TBCDRF_NOEDGES.

Comment: @Peter - I've updated the answer, button borders are not drawn now on also Vista and 7.

Comment: Awesome, thanks you both gave me a fish and taught me to fish - this is the best answer I've ever got on SO (and I've been using it since the beta)